# Smooth the edges of binary images (Face) using Python and Open CV

Tags: python, opencv

I am looking for a perfect way to smooth edges of binary images. The problem is the binary image appears to be a staircase like borders which is very unpleasing for my further masking process.

I am attaching a raw binary image that is to be converted into smooth edges and I am also providing the expected outcome. I am also looking for a solution that would work even if we increase the dimensions of the image.

[Problem Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlC2w.png)    [Expected Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKk7v.png)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do that in Python/OpenCV with the help of Skimage by blurring the binary image. Then apply a one-sided clip.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.exposure

# load image
img = cv2.imread('bw_image.png')

# blur threshold image
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (0,0), sigmaX=3, sigmaY=3, borderType = cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)

# stretch so that 255 -> 255 and 127.5 -> 0
# C = A*X+B
# 255 = A*255+B
# 0 = A*127.5+B
# Thus A=2 and B=-127.5
#aa = a*2.0-255.0 does not work correctly, so use skimage
result = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(blur, in_range=(127.5,255), out_range=(0,255))

# save output
cv2.imwrite('bw_image_antialiased.png', result)

# Display various images to see the steps
cv2.imshow('result', result)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

You will have to adjust the amount of blur for the degree of aliasing in the image.

Comment: I wonder if you could get better results with another filter such as [median](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.filters.html#skimage.filters.median)?

Comment: That's really great! Impressive output. Can I can put any size as the output size and the mask will be scaled?

Comment: How can we automate this task for multiple images? Say a directory?

Comment: @DesmondCheong Can u please provide the full code? That would be better.

Comment: I do not think a median filter will antialias well.

Comment: I was thinking a median filter or mode filter would work better because it preserves the sharpness of the image while still antialiasing, let me show an example.

Answer (score 9):

To preserve the sharpness of a binary image, I would recommend applying something like a [median filter](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/reference/ImageFilter.html#PIL.ImageFilter.MedianFilter). Here is an example of this:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter


image = Image.open('input_image.png')
image = image.filter(ImageFilter.ModeFilter(size=13))
image.save('output_image.png')
```

which gives us the following results:

[image: Input image] [image: Output image]

**Figure 1.** *Left:* The original input image. *Right:* The output image with a median filter of size 13.

Increasing the size of the filter would increase the degree of smoothing, but of course this comes as a trade-off because you also lose high-frequency information such as the sharp corner on the bottom-left of this sample image. Unfortunately, high-frequency features are similar in nature to the staircase-like borders.

Comment: OK. I see what you mean. But it does not actually smooth enough. It just reduces the aliasing to smaller steps.

Comment: @fmw42 Yes, your approach with skimage is better and more robust compared to this.

Comment: `@Pranav` Your approach is better than I thought it would be, though. Thanks for posting that and correcting me on that point. Depending upon what the OP wanted to do, your approach might be better than mine.