# Smooth surface of binary image

Tags: python, binary-data, smoothing

does anyone know of functions that smooth surfaces of binary masks (i.e. images of zeros and ones)?

I'm trying to get rid of these bumps without damaging other areas (e.g. the ears).

It would also be okay, for example, if the function removes such bumps, but in the ears it may only remove a maximum thickness of 1 pixel. I could then compensate that by `binary_dilation(mask[:,:,z])`.

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Smooth the edges of binary images (Face) using Python and Open CV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62078016/smooth-the-edges-of-binary-images-face-using-python-and-open-cv)

Comment: Take a look at something called morphology operators